# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter does't show previous and next buttons

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I'm playing a video using `AVPlayerViewController`, and I noticed that in now playing center, previous and next buttons were replaced with 15 seconds back and forth seeking buttons. The problem is that I need previous and next buttons to be visible. Also I set `updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter` property to `NO`.

See the images below for a better understanding:

**Current UI:**

[image]

**Wanted result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, I've found a solution: just disabled backward and forward `MPSkipIntervalCommand`:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *rcc = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

MPSkipIntervalCommand *skipBackwardIntervalCommand = [rcc skipBackwardCommand];
[skipBackwardIntervalCommand setEnabled:NO];

MPSkipIntervalCommand *skipForwardIntervalCommand = [rcc skipForwardCommand];
[skipForwardIntervalCommand setEnabled:NO];
```